# Showing the columns that are being merged on in output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using code such as below:

```
pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values('time'), df2.sort_values('time'), on='time', by='id')
```

I want the time column from df2 so be shown in the output as it is the only column that isnt shown in the output so I can see both times next to each other if that makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of 'time' prior to merging.

```
df2['time_copy'] = df2['time']
..... pd.merge_asof ...
```